# Postgres ltree in hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework-1.x, ltree

I use Play Framework 1.2.5.3 and PostgreSQL 9.x.

I have class `WorkArea` as db model with field

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "ltree", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String tree;
```

In the postgre it is a database table **workareas** with field **tree** (type **ltree**)

I want to use Hibernate query with postgres ltree operations. For example:

```
List<WorkArea> workAreas = WorkArea.find("tree @> :tree").bind("tree", otherArea.tree).fetch();
```

Or

```
List<WorkArea> workAreas = WorkArea.find("ltree_isparent(:tree, tree)").bind("tree", otherArea.tree).fetch();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a stored procedure you're going to need to use a native query.

```
Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("some sql query :foo", WorkArea.class);
query.setParameter("foo", "bar");
List<WorkArea> results = query.getResultList();
```